# JLabel not greyed out when disabled, when HTML text displayed

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, appearance

How do I get a `JLabel` displaying a HTML string to appear greyed out (which is the behaviour of `JLabel`s that don't display HTML text)? Is there another way than actually changing the colour myself by modifying the `foreground` property?

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Normal text");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("<html>HTML <b>text</b>");
// Both labels are now black in colour

label1.setEnabled(false);
label2.setEnabled(false);
// label1 is greyed out, label2 is still black in colour
```

---

Thank you very much for all of your responses. From what I gather, it seems that Java doesn't support automatic greying out of `JLabel`s when they use HTML text. [Suraj's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242542/jlabel-not-greyed-out-when-disabled-when-html-text-displayed/2242590#2242590) has come closest to the fix considering the limitations.

I have however, tried a different out-of-the box approach, where I have put the HTML text `JLabel`s inside of an inner `JPanel` and did this:

```
mInnerPanel.setEnabled(shouldShow); //shouldShow is a boolean value
```

Which hasn't worked. Any suggestions for this way?

---

EDIT: Added [implemented solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242542/jlabel-not-greyed-out-when-disabled-when-html-text-displayed/2249050#2249050).

Comment: you should edit your original question not post another one

Comment: @Lombo, my bad, I didn't realise - deleted the previous one now.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Java 1.7.

Comment: @SystemParadox thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If text is HTML, the text wont be grayed out because of the following code in `BasicLabelUI#paint()`

```
        View v = (View) c.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
        if (v != null) {
        v.paint(g, paintTextR);
        }
```

As you can see if the text is html, then the View is used to paint and  it is not checked wheter the label is enabled or not.
Hence we need to do it explictly as shown below:

```
label2.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if (!evt.getPropertyName().equals("enabled"))
     return;
    if (evt.getNewValue().equals(Boolean.FALSE))
     label2.setText("<html><font color=gray>HTML <b>text</b></html>");
    else
     label2.setText("<html><font color=black>HTML <b>text</b></html>");
   }
  });
```

Comment: `setForeground` works, so I'd suggest using that rather than altering the label text to change the colour.

Comment: Changing HTML might not be a good practice though as far as i am concerned.

Answer (score 5):

Implemented solution:

```
    Color foreground = (shouldShow) ? SystemColor.textText : SystemColor.textInactiveText;
    for (Component comp : mInnerPanel.getComponents())
    {
        comp.setForeground(foreground);
    }
```

Caved in and used `setForeground` in the end, as it appears that Java seems to explicitly ignore the `enabled` property when painting `JLabel`s so long as it contains HTML text. See also [@Suraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242542/jlabel-not-greyed-out-when-disabled-when-html-text-displayed/2242590#2242590), for "pure" solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following, which is combination of two solutions provided here:

```
public class HtmlLabel extends JLabel{
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){
        if(getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey) != null ){
            Color foreground = (enabled) ? SystemColor.textText : SystemColor.textInactiveText;
            setForeground(foreground);
        }
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the font color in the HTML.

Comment: @camickr: So I would have to do this every time the enabled / disabled state changes?

Comment: Yes, which is why using the setForeground() method is still the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Override the paint method in the UI,  set the client property **BasicHTML.propertyKey** to null if it is disabled and call super...

Comment: @sreejith...apparently it will not work, for two reasons a) if you set BasicHTML.propertyKey to null then any component using html rendering will fail to paint html b) though the text will be displayed in gray, it will display the entrie html i.e. it will display "<html>HTML <b>text</b>" instead of HTML text. :)